# What are the downsides of using hidden form fields to store values?

Tags: javascript, performance, security

What are the downsides of using hidden form fields to store values that would otherwise have to either be a global variable or be passed around from function to function.  For instance...  A variable like currentIndex that changes from song to song in a music player is hard to control with anything other than a global variable .  Well at least it is in my hacked up code.  My question is... Will storing this value in a hidden form field make my script run a lot slower, and or will doing this be introducing security issues?  Thanks for any help and my apologies if this is a duplicate.

Comment: please fix the title. It doesn't represent the question

Comment: The original wording of the question doesn't seem to be showing anger.

Comment: It won't be that big deal unless you have 1000000 ids in that page with lots of replication. Anyway, you should think about localstorage. There are js library that will fall back to other kinds of browser storage if local storage is not available. Basically IE 7+ upward is the minimal you need to support. Major browsers like Firefox and Chrome are okay with local storage, most people are probably using FF 10+ anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I do use local storage for somethings but from a speed standpoint wouldn't it be quicker to grab a value from a form field than get an item from local storage?  I've never tested it but it seems like it's worth a shot.  I might just name my variable something stupid like  "GUYS_WHO_CHANGE_OTHER_PEOPLES_QUESTION_TITLES_ARE_AWESOME = 0"

Answer (score 3):

> Will storing this value in a hidden form field make my script run a lot slower

No. Accessing the DOM is slower than accessing variables but it's unlikely you will notice a significant difference unless you are repeatedly accessing the value in a tight loop. For something that is accessed "from song to song" (i.e. once every few minutes) it will have absolutely no measurable impact.

> and or will doing this be introducing security issues?

It's not clear what sort of security issues you are refering to. If it was going to be a client-side variable anyway, your users could always tamper with the Javascript source code and modify the value of variables.

Comment: Storing that data won't make "a lot" slower, but accessing values of DOM elements is most certainly slower than a variable.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I've been watching to much Crawford on javascript.  I'm just going to use the global cause you are right, my script slowed way down when I'd hit the next button repeatedly but it never did that when I had the global.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to store data in hidden form fields if the data is not being submitted to the server.